# Move Skyrim quest progress to new character

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to try out the awesome new Epic Gameplay Overhaul, but have grown attached to my current mage, and EGO requires a new game. I'm curious how and if the universe will explode if I create a new character and use the console to:

- advance all quests I care about through all stages I completed one at a time.
- use console to give gold and items I care about (nothing unique/quest rewards involved).

I don't care much about losing levels/skills/items, but would like to keep quest progress.

Comment: Honestly I can't see that being a problem but Skyrim is so bad tempered I definitely recommend making a backup of your save data before doing anything like this.

Comment: My recommendation would be "make a backup, then try it and see."

Comment: +1'd you guys for recommending backups.  ALWAYS do backups when Skyrim or Fallout saves are involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving yourself items should never break the game (unless you give yourself quest items, but they are useless, so why would you?). Advancing quests with the console can be problematic (and, in the case of some quests, impossible) both because there are undocumented stages to most quests that can make important changes, and because things other than quest stages may be involved in the quest, such as opening passages, killing characters or acquiring items.

Overall I would recommend making a new character and playing the storylines you haven't played with your last character, then deciding whether you want to risk messing up your save or if you want to replay the old storylines again.